# Create method for typo fix including varying length, case and characters

Tags: java, string

I have been tasked to create a String method that will take any input with varying lengths and random capitalization and return a string that has the first letter as uppercase, and the rest as lower case.

Since the program we are building is solitaire, this method should return inputs such as "aarts," "HEARTS," "heartss," etc as "Hearts" and this would be the same for the other three suits.

I have figured out how to correct inputs that are randomly capitalized, but not for ones that are varying lengths or have typos. The code below is where I am trying to alter inputs.

```
    /**
 * Converts the given string to title case, where the first
 * letter is capitalized and the rest of the string is in
 * lower case.
 * 
 * @param s a string with unknown capitalization
 * @return a title-case version of the string
 */
public static String toTitleCase(String s)
{
    String result = "";

    result = s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    return result;
}
```

The next code is the code that I am using to test the code above.

```
    private void main()
{
    testToTitleCase("HEARTS", "Hearts");
    testToTitleCase("hEarts", "Hearts");
    testToTitleCase("HEART", "Hearts");
    testToTitleCase("hEaRtS", "Hearts");
    testToTitleCase("heartss", "Hearts");
}

private void testToTitleCase( String input, String expectedOutput)
{
    String actualOutput = Card.toTitleCase(input);

    System.out.println("Testing whether toTitleCase('" + input + 
        "') returns '" + expectedOutput + "'.");

    if (expectedOutput.equals(actualOutput))
    {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Failure! The actual output was '" 
            + actualOutput + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct typos, you can match the discrete characters of a string with original string and count the number of matches and implement accordingly. For example:

```
public static String verifyInput(String typo) {

    String correctString[] = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Ace", "Club" };

    // A number to store maximum matches
    int maxMatch = 0;

    // Final String
    String finalStr = "";

    // Iterate through array to find best match
    for (String corrStr : correctString) {
        int match = 0;
        String dis = "";

        // Form discrete string
        // We match only discrete characters
        for (char x : typo.toCharArray())
            if (corrStr.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(x).toLowerCase())
                    && !dis.contains(String.valueOf(x))) {
                dis += x;
                match++;
            }

        // Special stuff for ace
        if (corrStr.equals("Ace") && match > corrStr.length() / 2 && typo.length() == 3)
            return corrStr;

        // If the current string had more matches than previous, replace
        // previous with current
        if (match > maxMatch) {
            maxMatch = match;
            finalStr = corrStr;
        }
    }

    return finalStr;
}
```

---

Input: `heartss`, `aarts`, `HEARTS`, `aaarhzzzzs`, `farts`, `husthusahuiu`

Output: `Hearts`

---

Input: `spSUgyDz`

Output: `Spades`

---

Input: `ACD`

Output: `Ace`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm now wondering how to do this for the other suits, within this one method. Would I just have to create variable correctString for each suit?

Comment: Edited my answer. You call this method and pass the parameters as: `verifyInput(whatUserTyped, whateverIsCorrectOutput)`. This will return the corrected string. Although if user entered completely something absurd, this returns null. Afterall you are correcting typos, not making them say something random and matching it :)

Comment: Our method should only take in one parameter, so I can't change it to have two parameters.

Comment: Edited my code. Needs only one parameter (the typo string) now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I had been stuck on this for quite some time.

Comment: Hey so I continued working on my program, and noted that the method should also work for the varying ranks of the cards. It should return "Two, Three, etc" if the input is TWO or WO or HREE or three, etc. Not sure how to change the method, considering that now there are multiple strings with the same length as Ace.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the Levenshtein distance between the input string and each of the possible legal values ("hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"). The incredibly useful [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) library includes a function for that. The pair with the lowest distance is probably the right one - but make sure you set an upper threshold on the distance; if the user enters "sushi on rye with mustard" then one of the values will be a closer match than the others, but that won't mean it's the correct match.